# How to see that $X_0(N)$ has at least one cusp rational over $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory

Have some trouble understanding the argument on p45-46 in modular curves paper in Modular Forms and Fermat’s last theorem.  Specifically,how to see that the residue class degree of the restriction to $\infty$ to function field of $X_0(N)$ is $1$ and how this implies field of rationality of the corresponding cusp is $\Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the function field is $\Bbb{Q}(j,j_N)$ then it is clear that the $\infty$ cusp is rational as the $q$-series for $j,j_N$ have rational coefficients at $\infty$, whence so do any element of the function field, in particular those holomorphic at $\infty$ (forming the local ring at $\infty$)